# 'undefined is not a function' on object tag print()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

I am trying to print a PDF which is embedded in an object tag which is present in an Iframe.I am getting an error message saying 'undefined is not a function' with the below code in Chrome but it works perfectly fine in IE.

```
$('#iframeWindowDialog').contents().find('object[classid=clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000]')[0].print()
```

Can anybody suggest a code which works fine in both Chrome and IE ?

Comment: Have you tried find('object[classid="clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000"]')

Comment: It looks like `$('#iframeWindowDialog').contents().find('object[classid=clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000]')` can simply be `$('#iframeWindowDialog object[classid=clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000]')`. At least `.contents()` is useless here.

Comment: @artm from [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): _An attribute value can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string._

Comment: What is the print() function?

Comment: @artm there is [window.print()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp). Maybe OP is trying to use it in incorrect way.

Comment: @artm Print() function which opens the windows to print. With this I wanted to print only the section I have selected which is object tag.

Comment: @Regent I know the window.print() but unsure about the element.print(). Could it be it's defined on IE but not on chrome?

Comment: @artm yes, it can be so.

Comment: @Pradeep `.print()` works for `window`. If IE supports `.print()` for element - good for it.

Comment: @Pradeep As regent said, have a look at .print() function, might work for elements on IE but it's actually a window function. Chrome may not support it for elements.

Comment: @Regent Regent, completely unrelated but how do you mark sections of your comment as code blocks?

Comment: @artm The same way as it can be done in questions/answers: wrapping code with (if it's hard to see character that I have written - it is second character (without shift pressing) on `~` key) '`'

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar problem, and solved this way:

Instead of:

```
  var wf = window.frames["myframe"]
  wf.print()
```

I did

```
  var wf = window.frames["myframe"]
  wf.contentWindow.print()
```

and that did the trick :-)